# when to add 2nd element of linked list in c ,have bus error

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create linked list in C. A program accepts input data from user input. I am have  using for loop to iterates through in order to create linked list. C program crash with Bus error during 2nd iteration of loop when I try to copy new node to the struct pointer tail’s next.

Please give some suggestion how to fix the Bus error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Crating a node of linked list
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

// A function to create in linked list 
struct node *createLinkedList(struct node *head, int data)
{
    struct node *tail;
    struct node *new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new_node;   
        tail = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = new_node;  //// crash here during 2nd iteration
        tail = new_node;
    }
    return head;
}

// function to create a new_node node at the beginning of linked list.
struct node *insert_node(struct node *head, int data)
{

    struct node *new_node_node;

    new_node_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    new_node_node->data = data;

    new_node_node->next = head;

    head = new_node_node;

    return head;
}

// function to print the new_node linked list.
void print_list(struct node *head)
{

    struct node *print_node = head;

    printf("Linked list is:");

    while (print_node != NULL)
    {

        printf(" %d", print_node->data);

        print_node = print_node->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{

    struct node *head = NULL;
    int total_no_node, value, node_data;

    printf("\n How many node to create ?: ");

    scanf("%d", &total_no_node);

    for (int i = 0; i < total_no_node; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the integer for node: ");
        scanf("%d", &node_data);

        head = createLinkedList(head,node_data);

    }
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Please see attached screenshot of lldb debug[image: image1]

Comment: Turn the compiler’s warnings to max and go through the code line by line. What happens when head isn’t null? What is the value of tail?

Comment: Enable and head the warnings. I get `'tail' may be used uninitialized` when using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic.`  You *are* using `tail` without giving it  value first, so your program has undefined behaviour.